# vim undojoin and programmatic insert

Tags: vim, undo

For a vimscript plugin, [Vim-swoop](https://github.com/pelodelfuego/vim-swoop),

I'm trying to get `:undojoin | append(1, lineList)` work.

The issue is that the operations I want to join with user actions are called by:

`autocmd!    CursorMovedI   swoopBuf   :call   s:cursorMoved()`

So Vim won't merge action because in the 'build in mecanism' an undoblock is designed when exiting mode.

Does anyone has an idea of the approach i should adopt ?

Comment: What do you want? disable undo once?

Comment: Yes, but  i can't use the `set ul=-1` method because i want to keep history